# Особенности работы VSIX

Tags: c#, visual-studio, assembly, visual-studio-extensions

Собственно, этот вопрос отчасти является приквелом [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/877319/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-vsix-%D1%81-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA), однако тут поднимается совсем иная проблема, которая по контексту слишком расходится с описанной в вопросе по ссылке

---

Изначально я пользовался таким методом:

1. Получаю путь, по которому надо получить сборку
2. Проверяю, есть ли в моем словаре `Dictionary<string, Assembly>`
   ключ, равный указанному пути

   - Если есть - вернуть загруженную ранее сборку
   - Иначе - загрузить сборку, закэшировать ее в словарик и потом вернуть

И все работало как часы. Но только при первом запуске Visual Studio...)
При последующих ее запусках загрузка вылетала с ошибкой

Увы, я не могу отдебажить, что же там творится при втором запуске, так как проблема в экспериментальной инстанции Visual Studio не наблюдается

---

У меня складывается впечатление, что Visual Studio кэширует загруженные при последнем запуске сборки и при повторном открытии вновь выгружает их в текущий AppDomain

Однако это только догадка...

Хотелось бы услышать Ваши советы и мысли по данному поводу, ибо происходящее сейчас выглядит аки чистая черная магия)

---

### UPD:

Проверил список загруженных при запуске сборок. Старые там отсутствуют, так что проблема не в этом

Ещё одно важное дополнение: если я отключу автоматическую подгрузку динамических сборок сразу при запуске Visual Studio и сам загружу их после полного запуска - все работает

Отдебажить непосредственно запуск Visual Studio не получается ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Зачем гадать? Вы можете из VSIX вывести список сборок в текущем домене куда нибудь (в файл или окно отладки), чтобы проверить это на практике?

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, когда писал вопрос - на это уже не оставалось сил. Но таки да, могу. Через пару часов обновлю вопрос, исходя из этой информации

Comment: Вы вполне можете отдебажить. У вас же падает студия - прицепите к ней другую студию до падения (или создайте чистый проект и укажите для него стартовый действием запуск devenv.exe).

Comment: @PashaPash, ну, студия-то не падает, она пользовательские расширения в данном плане корректно обрабатывает. Просто я через лог ошибок это мониторил. Про `devenv` - надо попробовать, кстати

Comment: @Kir_Antipov почему именно не получается отдебажить запуск студии?

Comment: @Kir_Antipov создайте новый консольный проект. в свойствах проекта в Debug пропишите External Program: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe`. В Menu / Debug / Options снимите Enable Just My Code. Нажмите F5 и смотрите, какие исключения падают в output.

Comment: @PashaPash не знаю, что творит Visual во время запуска, но дебаг возможен лишь с того момента, когда все пакеты уже загружены

Comment: @Kir_Antipov в каком смысле "дебаг возможен"? Оно же сразу под отдладчиком стартует, с возможностью остановиться на исключениях. Да, брейкойнт по коду (F9) может подключивать - но можно или по имени метода поставить, или просто в коде прописать `Debugger.Break()` (или даже `Debugger.Launch()`). В вашем случае оно скорее всего падает с исключением, так что надо искать конкретное исключение в output, и включать остановку по нему.